# AD Group Authorisation .NET Core 8. IISExpress No authentication handlers are registered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-8.0

**EDITED**

This works in IIS but not IISExpress:

```
  var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CheckAdGroupHandler>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{

    options.AddPolicy("my_policy", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new CheckAdGroupRequirement("some_ad_group, another_ad_group"));

        policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string>()
        {
            IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
        };
    });

});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Where  CheckAdGroupHandler:

```
public class CheckAdGroupHandler: AuthorizationHandler<CheckAdGroupRequirement>
{
    protected override async Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context,
        CheckAdGroupRequirement requirement)
    {
        List<string> usersGroups = new List<string>();
        WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = (WindowsIdentity) context.User.Identity;
       
        using (var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, windowsIdentity.Name))
        {
            if (user != null)
            {
                foreach (Principal principal in user.GetGroups())
                {
                    string adGroup = principal.SamAccountName;
                    usersGroups.Add(adGroup);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var groupName in requirement.GroupNames)
        {
            if (usersGroups.Contains(groupName))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
        }

        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

and CheckAdGroupRequirement:

```
public class CheckAdGroupRequirement:IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    
    public List<string> GroupNames { get; set; }

    public CheckAdGroupRequirement(string groupNames)
    {
        GroupNames = groupNames.Split(',').ToList();
    }
}
```

Then decorating index.cshtml.cs thus:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "my_policy")]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
```

My launchSettings.json:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": true,
  "anonymousAuthentication": false,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:64205",
    "sslPort": 44374
  }
}
```

but I still get the following error when running locally from vs2022:

```
InvalidOperationException: No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add[SomeAuthHandler]("Windows",...)?
```

I've also tried editing the applicationhost.config all to no avail.  Has anyone else experienced this/know a fix for it?

Answer (score 0):

set "windowsAuthentication": true in the code or enable iis windows authentication enabled and disable others.

Make sure you have set up the program.cs file to handle authentication:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CheckAdGroupHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("my_policy", policy =>
    {
        policy.Requirements.Add(new CheckAdGroupRequirement("some ad group,another ad group"));
        policy.AuthenticationSchemes = new List<string> { IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme };
    });
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

Comment: yes I've tried that, still get the same error :(